# Why does space(n) <= time(n) imply that TIME(f(n)) is a subset of SPACE(f(n))?

Tags: complexity-theory

The title might be hard to understand, here's a picture of what I don't understand:

[image]

And further, why can we conclude this?
[image]

I thought about posting to theoretical CS stackexchange but it asks for research level and I don't think this will be accepted

Comment: What does the first inequality stands for? I'm speaking about $space_M(n) \le time_M(n)$

Comment: It's the relationship between the process time and space for a machine M for any given natural n.

Comment: Isn't it trivial? How can there be a situation for a machine $M$ that $space_M(n) > time_M(n)$?

Comment: I understand that, but I wasn't understanding the implication after the red arrow. The other user explained it though

Answer (score 3):

A machine which runs in time $f(n)$ also runs in space $f(n)$, that is, the space used by a machine is always at most the time it uses. In symbols, $\mathrm{space}_M(n) \leq \mathrm{time}_M(n)$.

A machine is in $\mathsf{TIME}(f(n))$ if it runs in time $O(f(n))$. Any such machine also uses space $O(f(n))$ (since the space used by a machine is at most the time it uses), and so it is in $\mathsf{SPACE}(f(n))$. In other words, $\mathsf{TIME}(f(n)) \subseteq \mathsf{SPACE}(f(n))$. This implies that
$$
\mathsf{P} = \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty \mathsf{TIME}(n^k) \subseteq \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty \mathsf{SPACE}(n^k) = \mathsf{PSPACE}.
$$
A similar calculation shows that $\mathsf{EXPTIME} \subseteq \mathsf{EXPSPACE}$.

For the remaining relation, we have to use a different fact about time and space: a machine which uses space $O(f(n))$ runs in time $O(2^{O(f(n))})$. This is because the number of configurations in a (one-tape) machine which uses space $O(f(n))$ is $|Q| f(n) |\Sigma|^{f(n)}$, where $|Q|$ is the number of states and $|\Sigma|$ is the size of the tape alphabet. You can check that this implies the remaining containment $\mathsf{PSPACE} \subseteq \mathsf{EXPTIME}$.

Comment: But why is it TIME(f(n)) subset/eq of SPACE(f(n)) and not the other way around? SPACE(f(n)) subset/eq of TIME(f(n)).

If SPACE(f(n)) is at most TIME(f(n)) then shouldn't the former be a subset of the latter?

Comment: I was thinking about it and got to a conclusion. It's because every machine that uses f(n) space, takes at least f(n) time, which means that there are SPACE(f(n)) machines taking more than f(n) time, thus there are more SPACE(f(n)) machines then there are TIME(f(n)) ones. 

Thank you!!